# Фильтрация массива по ключу из массива объектов

Tags: javascript

у меня есть 2 массивa

```
array1 = [1, 5, 2, 13, 14]
```

и

```
array2 = [{label: "label1", id: 14},{label: "label2", id: 5}]
```

подскажите как отфильтровать 1 массив по ключу id 2 массива.

т.е. получить

```
result = [5,14]
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно пройтись по ключам в массиве объектов, узнать, находятся ли такие же значения в первом массиве, и если да, то записать их в result:

```js
array1 = [1, 5, 2, 13, 14]
array2 = [{label: "label1", id: 14},{label: "label2", id: 5}]
result = [];
array2.forEach(function(item) {
  if(array1.includes(item.id)) { result.push(item.id) }
});
console.log(result)
```

А если нужно, чтобы было именно [5,14], а не [14,5], можно воспользоваться функцией `reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, что бы избежать переобхода в переобходе, можно вначале собрать `id` с `array2` в set и отфильтровать, это, также, поможет сохранить порядок в исходном массиве.

```js
const ids = new Set();
const array1 = [1, 5, 2, 13, 14]
const array2 = [{label: "label1", id: 14},{label: "label2", id: 5}]

array2.forEach((item) => ids.add(item.id));

const result = array1.filter((el) => ids.has(el));

console.log(result);
```